# Encrypt realm database and it crash

Tags: ios, realm

I need to encrypt realm file and I do like this in app launch.

```
- (void)encryptRealm {
    // Generate 64 bytes of random data to serve as the encryption key
    uint8_t buffer[64];
    SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 64, buffer);
    NSData *keyData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:sizeof(buffer)];

    // Create a Realm Configuration object with the encryption key
    RLMRealmConfiguration *configuration = [RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration];
    configuration.encryptionKey = keyData;

    // Attempt to open a Realm file with the encryption key
    NSError *error = nil;
    RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm realmWithConfiguration:configuration error:&error];

    // If the encryption key was not accepted, the error will state that the database was invalid
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
        return;
    }
}
```

And it crash like this. I am not sure what happen. How shall i do?
Tutorial is from here.

https://academy.realm.io/posts/tim-oliver-realm-cocoa-tutorial-on-encryption-with-realm/

> 2017-10-06 15:58:33.366167+0800 Alive 2.0[20770:6589296] ***
>   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason:
>   '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FA128FC0-BB80-469E-8B05-6B7957AD04A1/Documents/default.realm:
>   Unable to open a realm at path
>   '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/FA128FC0-BB80-469E-8B05-6B7957AD04A1/Documents/default.realm':
>   Not a Realm file.'

Comment: I assume you try to re-open the same file with two different encryption keys, which obviously won't work. You'd need to use the same encryption key to open it a second time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than generating a new key on each launch, you will need to store the encryption key used for a given Realm. The encryption example linked further down in that article has an [example of how to do this](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/examples/ios/objc/Encryption/LabelViewController.m#L112):

```
- (NSData *)getKey {
    // Identifier for our keychain entry - should be unique for your application
    static const uint8_t kKeychainIdentifier[] = "io.Realm.EncryptionExampleKey";
    NSData *tag = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:(void *)kKeychainIdentifier
                                               length:sizeof(kKeychainIdentifier)
                                         freeWhenDone:NO];

    // First check in the keychain for an existing key
    NSDictionary *query = @{(__bridge id)kSecClass: (__bridge id)kSecClassKey,
                            (__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag: tag,
                            (__bridge id)kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: @512,
                            (__bridge id)kSecReturnData: @YES};

    CFTypeRef dataRef = NULL;
    OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)query, &dataRef);
    if (status == errSecSuccess) {
        return (__bridge NSData *)dataRef;
    }

    // No pre-existing key from this application, so generate a new one
    uint8_t buffer[64];
    status = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 64, buffer);
    NSAssert(status == 0, @"Failed to generate random bytes for key");
    NSData *keyData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:sizeof(buffer)];

    // Store the key in the keychain
    query = @{(__bridge id)kSecClass: (__bridge id)kSecClassKey,
              (__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag: tag,
              (__bridge id)kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: @512,
              (__bridge id)kSecValueData: keyData};

    status = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)query, NULL);
    NSAssert(status == errSecSuccess, @"Failed to insert new key in the keychain");

    return keyData;
}
```